# CocoaPods not installing Alamofire in Swift Parse Chat App

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods, alamofire

I am trying to compile and run the following application (Swift Chat App using Alamofire).

[https://github.com/huyouare/SwiftParseChat](https://github.com/huyouare/SwiftParseChat/issues/4)

I am using ruby-2.0.0 ,  cocoapods 0.37.1, xcode 6.3, Alamofire 1.2.0

I am installing it using the normal `<pod install>` command. No errors or warnings during the process. 
However, when compiling, I get:

`No such Module 'Alamofire'`

If I install Alamofire manually, however, when compiling I get an `Apple Match-O Linker` Error :

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/cristian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftParseChat-btvjczpwjlekftetblbfrbposakh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods'
ld: framework not found Pods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is behind this??

Thanks !

Comment: Are you running it from `.xcworkspace`?

Comment: I noticed I was not loading from xcworkspace. Silly me. It seems like I did not read that part before.
Even though I still get Match-O errors, it is not the same question anymore. Please, you can add an answer and I will accept it, so it happens to less people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If everything is setup correctly, errors such as

> No such Module 'Alamofire'

occur when you build your project from `.xcodeproj`.

By default you need to build project integrating CocoaPods from `.xcworkspace`.

Comment: That was the fix. Such an easy mistake to make too. Thanks for the reminder.